# Use @Slf4j in a non-bean class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, slf4j, lombok

Below is an example. What is the best way to inject the logger into a non-bean instance without passing it through a parameter since my project has a lot of non-bean classes deeply nested?

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class SpringComponent {

    public String test() {
        log.info("method test called");
        A a = new A();
        a.run();
    }
}

public class A {

   public String run() {
        // I want to log here using Slf4j
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Slf4j` doesn't do any injection. It is a lombok annotation which will generate code for you when compiling. This basically means you can add it anywhere you want, it isn't tied to spring or anything else but lombok and code generation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not wrong @Slf4j works on non bean classes as well.
You can use it as shown below.

```
@Slf4j
public class A {

public String run() {
    log.info("logging works");
   }
}
```